# Visual select and break multiple lines in VIM up to textwidth

Tags: vim

If I have a few long lines like so

```
# I am Quater. Read my words, and be my friend.
# Father commands me to record the truth of history, so that readers will learn from those who went before.
# Therefore, I give each of my seven sons one of these self-engraving, history-recording klay walls.
```

I want to select the lines and issue a command and have it wrap to the text width while preserving the comment symbol (hashtag) to get the following

```
# I am Quater. Read my words, and be my friend.
# Father commands me to record the truth of 
# history, so that readers will learn from 
# those who went before. Therefore, I give each 
# of my seven sons one of these self-engraving, 
# history-recording klay walls.
```

I know there is a way to do this because I have done it before in VIM but I erased my `.vimrc` file and I can't find the solution anywhere on google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have Vim format the lines using the [`gq`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#gq) command. Either select the lines visually then use `gq`, or use `gq` followed by a motion (such as `gq}` to format until the next line), or use `gqq` with a count (`3gqq` to format the current line and the two that follow it).

For Vim to preserve comments, it needs two options to be set correctly. One is `'formatoptions'`, which needs to include `q` (to preserve comments over a `gq` operation), and the `'comments'` option, which needs to include `b:#` to indicate that lines starting with a `#` are comments.

You can set both for the current buffer using:

```
setl fo+=q com+=b:#
```

After those settings, using `gq` will keep the comment characters at the start of lines when auto-formatting a block of comments.

Comment: I suggest `gwap` instead of `gqap` to keep the cursor position.

Comment: @SergioAraujo Oh wow today I learned `gw`, that's really cool!